# Phrase matching between two Strings in Ruby

Tags: algorithm, strings, ruby

I've written a phrase-matching method to return the longest matching phrase from two Strings in Ruby. My method looks like this and works as expected:

```
class String
  def phrase_in_common(other)
    n = [size, other.size].min
    while n > 0 do
      other_words = other.downcase.split.each_cons(n)
      string_words = split.each_cons(n)
      matching_words = string_words.find { |cons_words| other_words.include?(cons_words.map(&:downcase)) }
      return matching_words&.join(' ') if matching_words
      n -= 1
    end
  end
end

>> string = "Hello world, please come to my house next week"
>> other = "Hello friends, please come to my party next week"
>> string.phrase_in_common(other)
=> "please come to my"
```

My question is, can (and should) this be accomplished in a more Ruby way, perhaps by replacing the `while` with an `Enumerable` method of some kind?

To clarify, the phrase-matching should be based on words, so for example:

```
>> "this phrase".phrase_in_common("his phrase")
=> "phrase"
```

Also, note that the method is case-insensitive in matching and uses the case of the subject String for the return value:

```
>> "Greatest Show On The Earth".phrase_in_common("Silliest Show on the Earth")
=> "Show On The Earth"
```

Comment: Are you looking for the longest substring, or things minus non `\w` characters?

Comment: Looking to match the longest substring, but I wouldn't want to pick up, for example, the comma before the matching string. So I wouldn't want my example to return ", please come to my"

Comment: Spec is [here](https://github.com/SplitTime/OpenSplitTime/blob/master/spec/lib/core_ext/string_spec.rb) if that's helpful.

Comment: Those preserve case, though.

Comment: Right--I want to match case-insensitive but preserve the case of the phrase that's returned, based on the subject String. Please see the last example I added to the question.

Comment: I'd go with what you have then, there's just too many quirks to your requirements. A simple longest case insensitive substring match is considerably less code, but doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: is this question still open?  why is moveson's name gray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to get the longest common subsequence.
There are several implementation of this algorithm and you can find an example on [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence#Ruby).

A working recursive implementation implementation could be:

```
# Split your sentence into words and manipulate the content. E.g.
# - downcase all chars
# - split by some chars such as space, punctuation and so on

def split_into_words(string)
  string.downcase.split(/[\s\.,;\'\"]/)
end

def longest_subsequence(xstr, ystr)
  return '' if xstr.empty? || ystr.empty?

  x, *xs = xstr
  y, *ys = ystr

  if x == y
    x + " " + longest_subsequence(xs, ys)
  else
    [longest_subsequence(xstr, ys), longest_subsequence(xs, ystr)].max_by {|x| x.size}
  end
end

def phrase_in_common(string1, string2)
  xstr = split_into_words(string1)
  ystr = split_into_words(string2)
  longest_subsequence(xstr, ystr).strip
end
```

This would pass all your specs, but it returns `''` instead of `nil` when the longest substring is empty.

You can slightly change this implementation to include int inside `class String` eventually

#### Edit 2017-10-04

As remarked by `moveson`, in Rails we can easily make this method to return `nil` instead of an empty string:

```
def phrase_in_common(string1, string2)
  xstr = split_into_words(string1)
  ystr = split_into_words(string2)
  longest_subsequence(xstr, ystr).strip.presence
end
```

Comment: I'm using Rails, so the last part is easily remedied by adding `.presence` after `.strip`.

Comment: I think it also needs `.squeeze(' ')` after the `.strip`. Otherwise it sometimes returns phrases with more than one space between words.

Comment: I haven't use squeeze it may have some [side effects](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/squeeze#995-Be-Advised)

Comment: About the `.presence` after `.strip` and I will edit my answer accordingly